# AngularJS dynamic routing from index to detailed page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to route from an index list of items to a page that will display a detailed view of that item.

In my index view I have a table that iterates through all the items that are saved in the database.

There is a button under the actions column that will take me to **events/show** route using `ng-click="go('events/show')"`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr scope="row" ng-repeat="event in events | reverse | filter:filterByUID">
            <td>{{event.title}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="actions">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="go('events/show')">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="events.$remove(event)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table looks like this: 
[image]

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
      $location.path( path );
    };
```

in my routes.js I have:

```
.whenAuthenticated('/events/show', {
        templateUrl: 'views/eventShow.html',
        controller: 'eventShowCtrl'
      })
```

Everything works so far.

However, what is unclear to me is how do I pass the event id to the eventShow.html page, so I know which item was clicked from the index list, so I can display the detailed information?

My firebase database looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Master detail example in Angular/Firebase:  https://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/m6spubtp/

Answer (score 1):

Check out ui-router, it makes dynamic routing much easier

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

But if you want to keep what you have, you should pass the event id into your path, like such

```
$scope.go = function ( path, event ) {
  $location.path( path + "/" + event.id );
};

.whenAuthenticated('/events/show/:eventId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/eventShow.html',
    controller: 'eventShowCtrl'
 })
```

and in your controller, access $stateParams.eventId to load that event.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a variable in your router:

```
.whenAuthenticated('/events/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/eventShow.html',
    controller: 'eventShowCtrl'
 })
```

Then you can simply use the ID in your function call:

```
go('events/:id')
```

[Here's a great tutorial](https://youtu.be/TRrL5j3MIvo?t=58m13s) (and I highly recommend watching all of both parts).

And you'll have nicer URLs that can be bookmarked.

Comment: I tried this, but it just sends me to the `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});`

What am I supposed to have in my go() function?

Answer (score 1):

One you could pass the UID(uid is just an example for user id) onClick

```
<tr scope="row" ng-repeat="event in events | reverse | filter:filterByUID">
  <td>{{event.title}}</td>
  <td class="col-md-2">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="actions">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="go('events/show', event.UID)">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="events.$remove(event)">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then in your js file

```
$scope.go = function ( path, uid ) {
  $location.path( path + "/" + uid );
};

.whenAuthenticated('/events/show/:eventId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/eventShow.html',
    controller: 'eventShowCtrl'
 })
```

Then to query firebase, say you have a field in your objects called `uid`, you can use `startAT` and `endAT` methods.

[See here for example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/vQEmt/2/)

And here to [read more on filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#filtering_data)

Comment: I tried this, however, the uid is coming up undefined when I `console.log($location.path( path + "/" + uid ));` The console reads: `LocationHashbangUrl {$$protocol: "http", $$host: "localhost", $$port: 9000, $$path: "/events/show/undefined", $$search: Object…}` The url in address bar is: `http://localhost:9000/#/events/show/undefined`

Comment: @livi1717 It's undefined, because uid doesn't exist, it's just an example for you. uid or id is an identifier, for example, in your database you have a dynamic key like -Knxxxxxxxxxx, you can then pass it to the url like 
`http://localhost:9000/#/events/show/-Knxxxxxxxxxxx`, with that id, you will be able to query your database, to get results under the firebase dynamic keys.